# JS Method Chaining Controlling Flow

Tags: javascript, typescript, design-patterns

I have created a method in Typescript which utilizes method chaining to create a simple sql query builder. It implements the basic query methods. What I would like to do is not allow someone to call the offset method for example if they havent called limit previously or calling where twice. I know I can implement something via a map which stores the previously called methods but I was wondering if there is a clean solution to this problem. My current query builder method is

```
public qb = () =>
{
    let query = this.SELECT;
    const api = {
        where: (key: string, value: number|string) =>
        {
            query = sql`${query} WHERE ${sql.identifier([key])} = ${value}`;
            return api;
        },
        and: (key: string, value: number|string) =>
        {
            query = sql`${query} AND ${sql.identifier([key])} = ${value}`;
            return api;
        },
        orderBy: (key: string, order: 'ASC'|'DESC') =>
        {
            query = sql`${query} ORDER BY ${sql.identifier([key])} ${order}`;
            return api;
        },
        limit: (limit: number) =>
        {
            query = sql`${query} LIMIT ${limit}`;
            return api;
        },
        offset: (offset: number) =>
        {
            query = sql`${query} OFFSET ${offset}`;
            return api;
        },
        get: async () => this.rowMapper(await this.database.query(query)),
    };
    return api;
};
```

Is there a nice way to force the flow of the method chaining?

Comment: Start by returning a *new* object instead of the same `api` every time

Comment: Thats true I can do but that I was wondering if there are any patterns I can use because I dont want to duplicate code. For example get would need to be on most flows

Comment: Yes, that suggestion was independent of how to avoid the code duplication, but I'd suggest to do that first to find out what kind of objects each method should return. Once you've written it out in detail (and possibly created interface types for it), you will hopefully find the pattern that allows you to get rid of the duplication.

Comment: Thanks, I think i found a pattern that works for the problem. I added an answer to the question that I think is the most optimal when it comes to reducing code duplication. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up going with is creating multiple objects which have different methods inside of them. The solution is not the cleanest but I could not find a better one

```
public qb = () =>
{
    let query = this.SELECT;

    const get = async () => this.rowMapper(await this.database.query(query));
    const limit = (_limit: number) =>
    {
        query = sql`${query} LIMIT ${_limit}`;
        return {
            offset: (offset: number) =>
            {
                query = sql`${query} OFFSET ${offset}`;
                return { get };
            },
            get,
        };
    };

    const api2 = {
        and: (key: string, value: number|string) =>
        {
            query = sql`${query} AND ${sql.identifier([key])} = ${value}`;
            return api2;
        },
        orderBy: (key: string, order: 'ASC'|'DESC') =>
        {
            query = sql`${query} ORDER BY ${sql.identifier([key])} ${order}`;
            return {
                limit,
                get,
            };
        },
        limit,
        get,
    };
    const api = {
        where: (key: string, value: number|string) =>
        {
            query = sql`${query} WHERE ${sql.identifier([key])} = ${value}`;
            return api2;
        },

    };
    return api;
};
```